# Amount of meat needed

Tags: raw-meat

How much beef brisket and how much pork butt  should I buy to feed 40 people. 95 % men. They will be making sandwiches and have slaw and dessert .Needed right away. Thanks..

Comment: In my experience, people tend to overeat brisket and under eat pulled pork.  I think this is because the pork (when pulled) looks bigger for its weight, and makes a bulkier sandwich.

Answer (score 2):

A typical brisket / pulled pork sandwhich has around 225-250g of meat on it, but to play safe I would overcount.